# Download a jar using java

Tags: java, jar, download

so, I have this set of code to download a file, it seems to think it works, but the downloaded file is corrupt.

> ```
>           try{
>                 java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new
>                     java.net.URL(args[1]).openStream());
>                 java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(args[2]);
>                 java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
>                 byte data[] = new byte[1024];
>                 int count;
>                 while( (count = in.read(data,0,1024)) != -1){
>                 bout.write(data,0,count);
>                 }
>                 fos.flush();
>                 fos.close();
>            } 
>            catch(Exception e){
>            }
> ```

args[1] is the URL

Comment: Are you sure the source isn't corrupt? I suggest that, if you haven't done so already, download the same file using a browser and verify that it is OK.  Then compare what you believe is a "good" version to the corrupted one and determine where the problem is.

Comment: i am positive, i have tried downloading many diffrent exes and jars, including minecraft.
i always check in my browser first, for 1. to make sure download works and 2. to see how long it should take

Comment: I went so far as to compile and test your code (with the modifications I suggested) and it works perfectly for me. You need to open the files in a text editor, as I said in a comment below my answer. Perhaps, for example, you're behind a proxy server, and your browser is set up for the proxy but Java is not; then then your files could contain, as I said, error pages instead of the intended contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're flushing and closing the `FileOutputStream`, and that's leaving some bytes behind in the `BufferedOutputStream`'s buffer; your files will be missing somewhere between 0 and 1024 bytes at the end. Change both of those calls to flush and close `bout` instead, and your problem will be fixed.

---

As an aside, this:

```
catch(Exception e){
}
```

is a programming sin of the highest order, and the source of many hard-to-diagnose problems -- not this one, this time, but it cold have been. If something is going wrong during your transfer, the error message will be silently ignored. Don't do this -- don't you ever, ever do this.

Comment: Those last two lines of the `try` block should be `bout.flush(); bout.close();` and the `catch` block should at a bare minimum contain `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: also, change fos.flush() and fos.close() to bout.flush() and bout.close() and still have the problem

Comment: You might try to determine *how* they're being corrupted. For example, look at the contents of the file in a text editor; maybe the files contain `404 FILE NOT FOUND` error pages!

Answer (score 1):

Empty catch blocks are usually not a good idea and can hide symptoms.

```
Change:
    catch(Exception e){ 
    } 
To:
    catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This would have been a great comment.  @John ***Never*** ignore exceptions in failing code.  That certainly does not help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sure you can download a .jar.
2. If you successfully download an .exe (which is nothing more than a binary stream of bytes, of arbitrary length), then I have no idea why you're having problems with a .jar (which is also just a binary stream).  The two should be 100%$ equivalent, from the perspective of your data stream.  My guess is that the .exe just *seemed* to work ... but you actually failed to copy some or all of the file.
3. Finally, it's worth noting that a ".jar" file is actually a ".zip" file.  You can wrap your stream in a built-in Zip class, and literally *interpet* the .jar contents as you read the file.  If you wish to do so.

Suggestion:

Check the file size and/or a checksum of the .exe's you copied.  Try a couple of different sized .exe's.  If you're satisified that the .exe is copying correctly, I assure you that the .jar should work, too.

Comment: hmm, let me try to fully run the exe and see what happens, i have a feeling you're right

Answer (score 0):

> After researching this simple code working fine for windows system
>   while for mac or other you need to change:

```
     import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
        import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
        import java.io.DataInputStream;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.net.URLConnection;
        import java.nio.channels.Channels;
        import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
        import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
        import java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

        /**
         *
         * @author aleem
         */
        public class Get {


           public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          /**Change the url with your jar file url**/
                String fileUrl = "http://elambak.com/Supported.jar";
    /**Assign any name to this newly downloaded file with destination location if required **/


                String destinationFile = "abc1.jar";

                saveFile(fileUrl, destinationFile);

           }
            public static void saveFile(String fileUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
                      int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

                URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

/** This user agent is using for windows for other OS need to change **/


              httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");

                int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
                    String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
                    int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();
                    InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }


            }

        }
```